# API or SDK for generating an AVI from bitmaps

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, animation, mfc

I have an C++ VS2010 Windows MFC/GDI application, and I'd like to be able generate an AVI to create an animation from a series of bitmaps.  Any recommendations for an appropriate API or SDK?

**edit:**   Not sure why this was closed, or how exactly it would 'likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion'?  Any rationale from those that closed it would be appreciated.

To provide a bit more context, my application is basically moving through a model, and capturing a series of screen shots into CBitmap objects.  I'm just looking for a method to programmatically compile these into a video format, such as AVI or MPEG.

Comment: MF (Media Foundation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694197(v=vs.85).aspx) is Microsoft's api for creating and consuming video of all kinds. I know it can create MP4s and WMVs, not sure about AVIs though. It may be a bit heavyweight for you simpler needs though.

Comment: Native Windpows APIs: Video for Windows, DirectShow, Media Foundation - pick the one you like. Popular third party option: libavformat/libavcodec/FFmpeg.

Comment: Thanks Roman, pretty much what I was looking for.  I'm not wild on the bloated MS APIs such as DirectX, I'll have a look at some of the 3rd party stuff.

Comment: Note that there is no DirectX on the list. The problem is compression/encoding. If you have small files you are happy to save as uncompressed AVI (big files, but less than 2 GB), then perhaps Video for Windows (AVIFile* family of functions beign out there for 15+ years), otherwise you will have to deal with compression.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **opencv** library. it's a powerful image processing library. it can import image and video in all formats and export it. opencv is a little advanced but it has enough tutorials.
more informations in [opencv website](http://opencv.org)

Comment: OpenCV as API for AVI file creation is similar to asking Superman to clean around.